# Router with MIMO upgrade antenna

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-router, antenna

I will be buying a dual band router for use in a small office environment. I will only be using the 2.4 band with this router and I want to upgrade one antenna. However there are three. 1 for 5 ghz a 2nd for 2.4/5 and a 3rd for 2.4 exclusively. Will only upgrading the 2.4 antenna cause the network to fail?

Comment: I have never heard of "upgrading" a consumer product like this.

Answer (score 0):

Why not upgrade all 3?   You may be surprised how fast the 5ghz network wants to be used. Later edition apple products (iPhone/iPad) specifically love 5ghz.  I've seen 3 packs of antenna's for about the same cost as 2 singles.

Comment: Its more of a money constraint and I have a high powered amp for one antenna.